# Div with selected options to filter another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<div style="float:center; width:auto; margin:5px 0px; text-align:center;">
 Please Select Your Alphabet:&nbsp;
    </div>
   <div style="float:center; width:auto; margin:5px 0px; text-align:center;">
  &nbsp;<select class="a1" id="ALPHA1" style="width:90%;">
         <option value="1">A</option>
         <option value="2">B</option>
         <option value="3">C</option>
         <option value="4">D</option>
        </select>
    </div><br>
  <div style="float:center; width:auto; margin:5px 0px; text-align:center;">
 Please Select Sub Alphabet:&nbsp;
 </div>
   <div style="float:center; width:auto; margin:5px 0px; text-align:center;">
  &nbsp;<select class="a1" id="ALPHA2" style="width:90%;">
         <option value="1">B1</option>
         <option value="2">B2</option>
        </select>
 </div>
```

I have a div with a selection of options. I want only one of the selected options to 'toggle' display of another div. This div will then have two possible options that can be selected.

I have tried a variety of solutions that all seem to involve the div 'toggling' text to appear but I want the toggle to be another div with selected options. I do need this to be in plain JS and not JQuery.

```
<div style="float:center; width:auto; margin:5px 0px; text-align:center;">
 Please Select Your Alphabet:&nbsp;
    </div>
   <div style="float:center; width:auto; margin:5px 0px; text-align:center;">
  &nbsp;<select class="a1" id="ALPHA1" style="width:90%;">
         <option value="1">A</option>
         <option value="2">B</option>
         <option value="3">C</option>
         <option value="4">D</option>
        </select>
    </div><br>
  <div style="float:center; width:auto; margin:5px 0px; text-align:center;">
 Please Select Sub Alphabet:&nbsp;
 </div>
   <div style="float:center; width:auto; margin:5px 0px; text-align:center;">
  &nbsp;<select class="a1" id="ALPHA2" style="width:90%;">
         <option value="1">B1</option>
         <option value="2">B2</option>
        </select>
 </div>
```

I only want the second div to appear if B is selected, and then to be able to pick B1 or B2 to proceed. I am assuming I need to write some sort of function but since the options are limited I wonder if there is another way to switch between the results. If not, how would I go about with the function?

Comment: Side note: `float` does not accept a value of `center`, so this part of your CSS will do nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I’m still figuring this stuff out. I’ve taken off float since I don’t think I need it with the center text align.

Comment: "I do need this to be in plain JS and not JQuery." What have *you* tried?

Comment: I attempted to write a function toggle() and pass that onclick to the div, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created the following snippet for you.

You just have to listen for the 'onchange' event on the first 'select' element and test its value (`e.target.value`) against the intended one.

```js
const select1 = document.getElementById('ALPHA1');
const select2Container = document.getElementById('ALPHA2Container');

select1.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === '2') {
   select2Container.style.display = 'inline';
    } else {
   select2Container.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="width:auto; margin:5px 0; text-align:center;">Please Select Your Alphabet:&nbsp;</div>
<div style="width:auto; margin:5px 0; text-align:center;">
    &nbsp;
    <select class="a1" id="ALPHA1" style="width:90%;">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
        <option value="4">D</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<div id="ALPHA2Container" style="display: none;">
    <div style=" width:auto; margin:5px 0; text-align:center;">
        Please Select Sub Alphabet:&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div style=" width:auto; margin:5px 0; text-align:center;">
        &nbsp;
        <select class="a1" id="ALPHA2" style="width:90%;">
            <option value="1">B1</option>
            <option value="2">B2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to implementing the function to show and hide the second input box, I did a fair bit of refactoring to consolidate duplicated code. The code I've written more or less follows best practices for HTML structure, and is much cleaner and easier to understand.

- According to the current accepted standards for web development, CSS should almost always be located in an external CSS file, not defined inline. It will likely work fine either way, but using a class definition to reference the CSS eliminates a lot of duplicated code.
- Several of the divs in your code weren't needed and could be removed. Doing this actually results in a more usable, accessible site, as it allows screen readers to visualize the hierarchy of the page.
- I've used CSS [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to stack the label on top of the select box so the `<br>`s aren't necessary. This step isn't strictly required, but is more extensible long-term than using `inline` display.
- Lastly, using a `<label>` element to encapsulate the label text for the dropdown instead of a div improves accessibility further. It makes it so that users can navigate to and click on that label in order to activate the dropdown, and also groups the two elements (label and select) logically for screen readers.

```js
// Find the select element that we want to monitor, and watch for change events.
document.getElementById('ALPHA1').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // Whenever the selection changes, if it's equal to 2 ("B")...
  if (e.target.value === "2") {
    // Add a class to the second dropdown that tells it to display.
    document.getElementById("subalpha").classList.add("show");
  } else {
    // If the selection is any other value, then remove the class to tell the second dropdown to hide.
    document.getElementById("subalpha").classList.remove("show");
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container select {
  width: 90%;
}

#alpha {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#subalpha {
  display: none;
}

#subalpha.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="alpha" class="container">
  <label for="ALPHA1">Please select your alphabet: </label>
  <select class="a1" id="ALPHA1">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="subalpha" class="container">
  <label for="ALPHA2">Please select sub alphabet: </label>
  <select class="a2" id="ALPHA2">
    <option value="1">B1</option>
    <option value="2">B2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

JAVASCRIPT Version:

```
document.getElementById('ALPHA1').onchange = function () {
    x = document.getElementById('ALPHA1').value = this.value;
    document.getElementById('secondDiv').style.display = "none";
    if (x == 2) {
        document.getElementById('secondDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
};
```

jQuery:

```
$("#ALPHA1").change(function () {
    $("#secondDiv").css('display', 'none');
    if ($("#ALPHA1").val() == 2) {
         $("#secondDiv").css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="firstDiv">
    <div style="position:relative;width:400px;margin:0 auto;">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            Please Select Your Alphabet:
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <select class="a1" id="ALPHA1" style="width:100%;">
                <option value="1">A</option>
                <option value="2">B</option>
                <option value="3">C</option>
                <option value="4">D</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="secondDiv" style="display:none;">
    <div style="position:relative;width:400px;margin:0 auto;">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            Please Select Sub Alphabet:&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <select class="a1" id="ALPHA2" style="width:100%;">
                <option value="1">B1</option>
                <option value="2">B2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Good Luck.